# Is R's names function equal to Pandas df.columns?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I'm given a task of converting an R script to Python. I'm trying to understand the functionality.

It is mentioned as below in the script.

```
#get id for single_triad
id <- names(forecast_object_list[single_triad_index])
```

**forecast_object_list** is something that is returned from **R's by() function**. I'm not sure if it's going to be a *list* or *dataframe* in R.

**single_triad_index** is an integer counter in a **for loop**.

What does this **names()** function actually do?

I don't have access to databases that are used in the R script to execute and look at the format of data.

After some research, I understood that it is returning **headers** in a dataframe. http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/names.php

Does that mean I can use pandas's df.columns to get the column names from a dataframe like:

`list(my_dataframe.columns.values)`

Are these two equal? or am I assuming it wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what the data format would be and how many columns would be there with the actual data as I don't have access now. I tried with sample dataframe and I got the column names. I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything during conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`names()` returns the names of an object's elements. For example, if we call `names` on each of the following elements R will return `[1] "a" "b"`:

```r
ve <- c(a = 1, b = 2) # atomic vector
li <- list(a = 1, b = 2) # list
df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2) # data frame
```

For your purposes it would worth knowing that data frames are just a special kind of list - `is.list(li)` and `is.list(df)` will both return `TRUE`. That means that, depending on what you are doing, you frequently don't need to differentiate between these two data objects. That said, sometimes there are differences, e.g. while `names()` works for both data frames and lists, `colnames()` will only work for data frames (and matrices, etc.). It ultimately depends on the available attributes.

If we compare the above to Python then the result seems to be the same. I think the main difference is that `names()` is a generic accessor that can be used with multiple data object types, while `.columns` is a specific attribute of the Pandas `DataFrame` object.

```py
df = DataFrame({'a':[1], 'b':[2]})
df.columns.to_list()
# ['a', 'b']
```